# Issue with creating a reusable method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What's the best way to refactor the following randomizing code into a reusable method? I want to put this part into a reusable method ==>`$scope.randTarotImg = $scope.tarotImg[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.tarotImg.length)];`

I tried the following and it's not working:

```
function randTarotImg(){
          $scope.randTarotImg = $scope.tarotImg[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.tarotImg.length)];
}     
$scope.onClick = function() {
     randTarotImg();  
};
```

Here's the relevant code block:

```
.controller('TarotCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.tarotImg = [];
      for (var i=1;i<=6;i++) {
      $scope.tarotImg.push(i);
    }  

    $scope.randTarotImg = $scope.tarotImg[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.tarotImg.length)];

    $scope.onClick = function() {
          $scope.randTarotImg = $scope.tarotImg[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.tarotImg.length)];  
    };

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

function getRandomElement(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
}

console.log(getRandomElement(arr));
```

In your case:

```
.controller('TarotCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.tarotImg = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    $scope.tarotImg.push(i);
  }

  function getRandomElement(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
  }

  $scope.randTarotImg = getRandomElement($scope.tarotImg);

  $scope.onClick = function() {
    $scope.randTarotImg = getRandomElement($scope.tarotImg);
  };

});
```